# Update UI on save: Local vs Server

Tags: javascript, rest, model-view-controller

Let's say I have a classic TODO app.

The app state is saved in an object, and the view is rendered based on the object. Ex.

```
let state = {
    items: [
     {id: 1, task: "Get milk"},
     {id: 2, task: "Feed chickens"}
    ]
}

render(state);
```

I want to update the UI after each TODO item save.

**Do I do update the UI locally or from the server?**

**Local**

```
POST api/items
After 200 response, state.items.push(item); 
render(state)
```

I'm afraid that this approach may lead to inconsistencies between the UI data and the server data.

**Server**

```
POST api/items
state.items = GET api/items
render(state)
```

I'm afraid that this approach makes a ton of unnecessary API calls.

Answer (score 0):

it is better to update the UI after you get the response from the server.

you don't have to request another GET request, you can simply return your data with the response of POST.

```
response = POST api/items
state.items = response.items
render(state)
```